# how to check if string is valid XHTML using PHP?

Tags: php, xhtml

Using

```
    $html = '<br /><p>k</p>';
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = New DOMDocument();
$dom -> loadXML($correo_elhtml);
echo '<pre>';
if(empty(libxml_get_errors())){
    echo "This is a good HTML";
    }
else {
    echo "This not html";
    print_r(libxml_get_errors());
    }
```

return ERROR, however that is a valid XHTML STRING.

Some function please?

Comment: Well-formed XML has a single root node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is a correct HTML but is NOT correct as XML, because empty-element tag, such as `<br />` in XML must used only between `<section></section>`

So you can use `$dom -> loadHTML($html);` or remove `<be />` from your HTML and then use `$dom -> loadXML($html);`

Comment: Thanks masters @Alohci and @Ehsan. Then a practice infalible to test ANY string is: `$dom -> loadXML('<div>'.$html.'</div>');` ?

Comment: @Stackoverflow please mark my response as your question answer

Comment: Master @Ehsan I doit many hours back: `https://pasteboard.co/JWSM6l1.png`

Comment: Master @Ehsan [I done it many hours back!](https://pasteboard.co/JWSM6l1.png).

Comment: @Stackoverflow Thanks but I mean https://pasteboard.co/JWVCRum.png

Comment: oh god! by first time I see this option. SORRY. Just I put in this option now. Many thanks by your lesson #2 :-)